# Unable to get Twilio Video working

Tags: ios, swift, video, avfoundation, twilio

I am using [Twilio Video QuickStart, Swift](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-swift), while I was able to make a video call using the example, but I couldn't make it work when I bundled all of it into one class and used in my app's viewController.

**Here is what I did:**

I've put all the Twilio Code in one `class VideoCall` as shown below, so that I could use the Twilio Video in whichever Controller I need, by just calling `VideoCall(myViewController: self)` as shown below.

While the below code creates both views (videoView & subVideoView) and renders local video in subVideoView as intended, it comes up with an Error when an incoming call is received

> TwilioVideo:[Platform]:Fatal runtime capture error: Error
>   Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be
>   completed"

However, I don't receive this error, when I put all the variables and functions into the `class mainViewController` instead of a separate `class VideoCall`, but this means I would be duplicating the code if I need to use Twilio Video in other View Controllers.

More info on Twilio `class TVIVideoView` which says

> A `TVIVideoView` draws video frames from a `TVIVideoTrack`.
>   `TVIVideoView` should only be used on the application's main thread.
>   Subclassing `TVIVideoView` is not supported.
>   UIViewContentModeScaleToFill, UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill and
>   UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit are the only supported content modes.

Please advice how I could get around this issue.

```
class mainViewController : UIViewController{

    //Declare variable in my viewController
    var videoCall           : VideoCall!

    // And create an instance
    fun viewDidAppear(){
        videoCall  =  VideoCall(myViewController: self)
    }
}


class VideoCall: NSObject {

    // Declared variables for Twilio Video
    var subVideoView    : TVIVideoView!
    var videoView       : TVIVideoView!
    var viewController  : UIViewController

    var accessToken = "TWILIO_ACCESS_TOKEN"

    // Configure remote URL to fetch token from
    var tokenUrl = "https://testapp.com/getTwilioVideoAccessToken"

    // Video SDK components
    var room: TVIRoom?
    var camera: TVICameraCapturer?
    var localVideoTrack: TVILocalVideoTrack?
    var localAudioTrack: TVILocalAudioTrack?
    var participant: TVIParticipant?
    var remoteView: TVIVideoView?

    // CallKit components
    let callKitProvider         : CXProvider
    let callKitCallController   : CXCallController
    var callKitCompletionHandler: ((Bool)->Swift.Void?)? = nil
    var callConfiguration       : CXProviderConfiguration

init(myViewController: UIViewController) {
        viewController      =   myViewController

        let callConfiguration = CXProviderConfiguration(localizedName: "Video Call")

        callConfiguration.maximumCallGroups = 1
        callConfiguration.maximumCallsPerCallGroup = 1
        callConfiguration.supportsVideo = true
        print("configuration: \(callConfiguration)")

        if let callKitIcon = UIImage(named: "iconMask80") {
          callConfiguration.iconTemplateImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(callKitIcon)
        }

        callKitProvider = CXProvider(configuration: callConfiguration)
        callKitCallController = CXCallController()
        super.init()
        subVideoView        =   TVIVideoView.init(frame: CGRect.zero, delegate: self)
        videoView           =   TVIVideoView.init(frame: CGRect.zero, delegate: self)
        callKitProvider.setDelegate(self, queue: nil)

        setup()
  }
  deinit {
    // CallKit has an odd API contract where the developer must call invalidate or the CXProvider is leaked.
    callKitProvider.invalidate()
  }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setup(){
      // The following is done here
      // a. videoView and subVideoView are made subViews of window, so that they are overlaid on top of the viewController
      // b. Setting size and position of videoView and subVideoView
    }

}

extension VideoCall{

    /* 
    Has all the callKit methods and Twilio methods, same as the example app but with these changes 
    a.the remoteView in the example app is replaced with videoView and screamed on initialisation, unlike Twilio Video example where it is created when connected to the room and cleared after disconnecting. 
    b. previewView is replaced with subVideoView.
    */

}
```

Comment: Can you share the differences with `remoteView` that sounds like it might have something to do with this?

Comment: In Twilio example code remoteView is setup when participant adds his video track, whereas I am creating it on load of the viewController and hiding it. When connected to the room, thats when I am unhiding it.

Comment: Yeah, that. Can I see the code for that! It's easiest if you edit your question to show it.